# passing string from C++ to C# using void pointer

Tags: c#, c++, string, dll

I am having C++ code like this just to try out to get the string to C# application from c++ dll.

```
int GetValue(void *pBuffer)
{
    int x = 0;
    String^ temp;
    temp = "TestStringtest1test2";

    memcpy(pBuffer, &temp,sizeof(temp));

    Console::WriteLine(temp);
    return x;
}
```

on c# side all I am doing is

```
[DllImport("Cplusplusapp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int GetValue(StringBuilder pBuffer); 

  StringBuilder Buffer = new StringBuilder(100);
  int x = GetValue(Buffer);
  Console.WriteLine(Buffer);
```

I have tried marshalling and various other suggestions but I am not able to understand why I am getting garbage values.Its fairly simple but what is that I am missing.

Comment: address of "temp" IS NOT string itself then memcpy won't work as expected.

Comment: Why would you even do this? Why pass a pointer between two languages that can handle .NET types? If your C++ is in fact C++/CLI, as the use of String^ suggest, why not have a String^ as parameter? Or better yet as return value? Why is it even used as an unmanaged import?

Answer (score 0):

Address of `temp` IS NOT string itself then `memcpy` won't work as expected. Moreover `sizeof(String)` will return size of `System.String` object (4 bytes on 32 bit machine), not string length.

If you need to copy a value from a managed string to an unmanaged pointer you have to follow next steps.

First of all `System.String` is always UNICODE then you won't have `char*` but `wchar_t*` (but you can convert it to what you need with usual helper macros). To convert a string from `System.String` to `wchar_t*` call `Marshal::StringToBSTR()`:

```
String^ temp = L"My string";
BSTR bstr = Marhshal::StringToBSTR(temp);
memcpy(pBuffer, bstr, SysStringLength(bstr));
Marshal::FreeBSTR(bstr);
```

Of course if you do not need to use a `System.String` you can skip all of these simply not assigning your string to `System.String`. Change it to `wchar_t*` or `char*` according to how you'll import that function (`CharSet.Ansi` or not), take a look to other `Marshal::StringToXYZ` functions, I would create e temporary string from `System::String` and then I would `strcpy` to destination buffer (check functions with Ansi suffix for `char*` versions). See [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881559/why-cant-i-see-some-c-dll-support-clr-in-c-sharp-project/10881908#10881908) for an example of that.